# Add bar labels in ggplot2 R 3.0.3

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a count label a `geom_bar()` chart. The data is in the format of a `Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1"`

Right now I have the following code but get an error of `'count'` not found.

Here is my code of my most recent try:

```
ggplot(mb,
       aes(x = Intervention_grp,
           y = ..count..,)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Intervention_grp),
           alpha = (1 - 0.618)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Intervention_grp),
            vjust = -0.2)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'count' not found
```

I see in the R Graphics Cookbook the following code:

```
ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x=ineraction(Date, Cultivar), y=Weight)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label=Weight), vjust = -0.2)
```

So I tried it in a similar format, just not using the interaction

```
ggplot(mb,
       aes(x = Intervention_grp,
           y = Intervention_grp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label=sum(as.numeric(Intervention_grp))),
            vjust = -0.2)
```

My result is two bars one for group 0 and one for group 1 with a label of 1519, there aren't that many observations in the data set.

How do I properly get the labels in there with the counts?

When I do the following:

```
ggplot(mb,
       aes(x = Intervention_grp,
           y = ..count..,)) +
  geom_bar()
```

I get an appropriate bar graph with the correct counts on the y axis, I just want to put them on the bars themselves.

Thank you,

Comment: See `sjPlot` package and `sjp.frq` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Count` column first. Here it is with the `plyr` package:

```
mb <- merge(mb, ddply(mb, .(Intervention_grp), summarise, Count=length(Intervention_grp), by = 'Intervention_grp')
```

Then you can use

```
geom_text(aes(label = Count, y = Count), vjust = -0.25)
```

---

## Example

```
iris2 <- iris[sample(seq_len(150), 50), ]
iris2 <- merge(iris2, ddply(iris2, .(Species), summarise, Count = length(Species)), by = 'Species')
ggplot(iris2, aes(x = Species)) + geom_bar() + geom_text(aes(label = Count, y = Count), vjust = -0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. I saw similar posts but tried doing `install.packages("ddply")` and could not because I use 3.0.3 and did not realize plyr would give me the necessary functionality.

Comment: `plyr` and `dplyr` are packages. `ddply` is a function within the `plyr` package